# How to get and set the byte in EEPROM - Waveshare AT24/FM24 using i2cget and i2cset command?

Tags: i2c

My raspberry pi is 3 Model B v 1.2.

I have changed the i2c baud rate to

The configuration in my raspberry pi are

```
# cat /boot/config.txt
# For more options and information see
# http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on,i2c_arm_baudrate=10000
dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

enable_uart=1

#core_freq=250
dtoverlay=w1-gpio
```

I am following the tutorial https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_Tutorial_Series:_I2C

I see that there are four address here.

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: 50 -- 52 -- 54 -- 56 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

When I remove the vcc connection of this EEPROM chip, I see that the i2detect shows nothing.
But when I plug it back, it says four addresses. Why there are four addresses?

When I do

```
# i2cget -y 1 0x50
0xff
```

But when I do this again

```
# i2cget -y 1 0x50
Error: Read failed
```

Comment: My comments to the following question might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101598/i2cdetect-shows-two-device-address.

Comment: It doesn't help since I can't even write anything on the address - 0x50. For e.g. -  i2cset -y 1 0x50 0x00 0x40

Comment: Ah, let me see.  My command "i2cdetect -y 1" gives only one address, but yours gives 4.  So first thing first is to solve the too-many-fake-addresses problem.  Have you tried the suggestions in my comments?  Of course I can try to reproduce your fake addresses by (1) increasing I2C speed higher and higher, until I also get three more fake addresses, (2) making my connecting wires longer and longer, until I also get fake addresses.  But that does not solve your problem.  So perhaps you can decrease I2C speed and shorten the wires, to see if you can reproduce my no fake address situation. :)

Comment: I am giving 3.3Volts to this sensor, is that fine?

Comment: yes, that is fine.

Comment: I changed the baud rate to 400000 and now I see the consistent - 50: 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57

Comment: Oh my goodness, But the suggestion in my very first old comments is to decrease the speed to as low as 10 kHz.  But now you are increasing to 400 kHz!

Comment: If I make 10Khz then nothing is detected at all.

Comment: are you using Rpi4B?

Comment: The datasheet for AT24c256 says max freq for 3v3 is approx 400kHz. No min freq is mentioned.  Usually 10kHz is OK. Let me think again. http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/doc0670.pdf

Comment: MagPi Page 46 says: To set I2C baud rate  to 10 kHz, add to  /boot/config.txt
dtparam=i2c_arm_baudrate=10000, Please confirm your statement is correct.  Of course you can try something between 400kHz and 10kHz.

Comment: Yes, I am changing this in the /boot/config.txt only - i2c_arm_baudrate=10000. I am using raspberry pi 3 model b v 1.2. I have added more information in my question now.

Comment: Quick comment: Only Rpi4B can change I2C speed, Rpi3B+ stretch CANNOT!!!  (Not sure about Rpi3 though) You might need to read my old comment once more.

Comment: In case your Rpi3 cannot change the fixed I2C speed of 100kHz, then you can try other troubleshooting ways: (1) shorten I2C wiring, to say less than 15cm, (2) use Vcc = 5V, and at the same time, convert Rpi3 3V3 I2C signals to 5V, using a logical level converter, (3) get another Rpi or EEPROM to compare and contrast.